# Unable to compile this on Xcode due to AudioFileID

Tags: xcode

[image]I'm trying to code using examples in "Learning Core Audio" book. This is the first example
There's a piece of code where I need to declare

```
AudioFileID audiofile
```

This example has no other imports.
Any clues or any new files to include. I'm running Xcode version 12.4
This project is a command line project on mac OS and am using Objective C

Error is here

```
//
//  main.m
//  CAMetadata
//
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    if (argc < 2){
      // insert code here...
        printf("Usage: CAMetadata /full/path/to/audiofile\n");
    }
  }

  NSString * audioFilePath = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[1]] stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
  NSURL *audioFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFilePath];
  **AudioFileID audioFile;**
  OSStatus theErr = noErr;
  theErr = AudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef) audioFileURL, kAudioFileReadPermission , 0, &audioFileURL);




  return 0;
} // end of main
```

Comment: add  "import AudioToolbox" (without quotes) at the top of your file.

Comment: Still getting an error when I add import AudioToolbox

Comment: Because what john elemans said is wrong....

Comment: try `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`

Comment: Thanks that works!

Comment: sorry, I was thinking in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

This will cause that line to compile:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

You will also need to disable ARC in order to get the rest of that code to compile.

However, this isn't what you asked, but I'm going to recommend that you drop the study of this book. It's too old. The code you are looking at is C and Objective-C, without ARC, and you are trying to run it in a command line tool which is not going to work in general because the program won't persist long enough to do anything with sound.